# How does makefile select the header file from those duplicates?

Tags: include, makefile, duplicates

here comes a short story

These days I tried to trace the compile process of the `Makefile`. According to the `EDK override mechanism`, a component while be compiled by using the source code of the same name under the override path and the remaining under the component's directory.

Assume that there have two header file of same name, the directory path as following:

component directory - `D:\outside\inner\hello.h`
override directory  - `D:\outside\inner\overrides\hello.h`

So, `D:\outside\inner\overrides` is used during compiling.

But, here comes a question!

It's known that we could add the macro in the Makefile to indicate the include paths.
For instance:

`INC = -I D:\outside\inner`

then I added another include path like:

`INC = $(INC) -I D:\outside\inner\overrides`

If I set the command in the Makefile like:

`hello : hello.c hello.h`
`<Tab>gcc -c hello hello.c $(INC)`

Will the compiler still take the hello.h file under the override path?
Or will it just takes the first found file through the INC path(component path)?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc` will use the first header it finds in the include paths. You can double check this my intentionally making a syntax error in one of the header files and looking for an error message. Or put this in overrides header:

```
 #warning "using overrides header"
```

and look for a warning message.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just test to add the error code in the first header in the include path, and the error message really only occurs when the first file is compiled. It has no response for the error code in the second header in the include path.

Comment: It's the same way for the CL.exe to control MS C and C++ compiler and linker not to compile the second file when the first file is found.